# How to create a Thread for particular member function in Qt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I would like to create a thread in Qt for partcular member function.  I want to call that thread once after he clicks the "ok" button in Gui. How do I do this? It would be helpful if anybody could provide an example.

Note: I cannot able to inherit from QThread.

Comment: Have you bothered to look in the Qt help files, or even a basic web search?

Answer (score 3):

The GUI itself is in the main event loop, a kind of "thread" on its own. You should do is have the alarm object fire off signals to your GUI. Now if you want to place it in a thread, read [this](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) to explain how to use thread properly in Qt. But for what you're doing a simple connection between the GUI and your alarm object is all that is needed.